# Newline \n Characters between Double Quotes Simple Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a single line string like so (trying to turn it into a properly formatted csv):

```
customer id,description,card country\nBZkvIP2FFfhA3s,"Customer\n10019\nUS\n55769 - example@email.co,",US\nBZiFuAQ6Bd7iNw,"EVV c/o Company\r\n47713\r\nUS\r\n55761 - email@example.com",US\n
```

I want to find a simple regex that I can use to replace the `\n` characters that are in the "description" (which is always between double quotes) with a space, then I will do a replace for the remaining `\n` characters (which will be at the end of the csv line. So my end result will be formatted like so:

```
customer id,description,card country
BZkvIP2FFfhA3s,"Customer 10019 US 55769 - example@email.co,",US
BZiFuAQ6Bd7iNw,"EVV c/o Company\r 47713\r US\r 55761 - email@example.com",US
```

I can't figure out how to do this simply, I don't need a regex that handles a million exceptions, just matches all `\n` that are between `"` and `"`

Comment: Searching using `\\n(?!(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` and replace with `" "`

Comment: @anubhava when i copy and paste that into my VS Code Find window it just freezes the program. Is there a simpler version?

Comment: Newlines between double quotes **IS** proper for a CSV file. If your string has literally `\n` as text and not a newline delimiter then you need to search for `\\n` and replace it with `\n`; or at least that is the sane way to do this with Notepad++. If you honestly think you need regex then see https://regex101.com/r/djG74I/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yep the newline within the quotes is proper, but I don't actually have newlines in my source, it's all a single line with newline characters, so I really need to replace the newline characters that are NOT in quotes with an actual newline but I figured it would be easier to replace the ones within quotes first then just replace the remaining newlines. Your regex almost works but I'm not sure how to just replace the group match char in VS Code.

Comment: @goddamnyouryan I've never used Visual Studio but I assume it has access to capture groups, correct? Example, `$1` usually, or `\1` in Python. If so then try https://regex101.com/r/djG74I/2 for your search and `$1 $2` as the replace.

Comment: I still do not fully understand what you are doing but it sounds like you're going to corrupt the CSV data so make sure to save a copy.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that was perfect. If you respond as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: What do you hope to do with the `\r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as the "search" term:

```
(".*?)(\\n)(.*?")
```

and for your "replace" you need:

```
$1 $3
```

https://regex101.com/r/djG74I/4

Comment: This will match `\n` outside `"..."` also. Check this: https://regex101.com/r/djG74I/5 And anyway it is matching just one `\n` inside `"..."` instead of all the `\n` as desired by OP.